Android studio - barteksc AndroidPdfViewer: how to add this as a module in my project?
How do I properly add this(text) as a module in my project?
I'm getting this error :enter image description here
I tried following this: text
but the method seems outdated
Also, I want to add this as a module because it comes from jcenter only and its deprecated now
